# Get information from a document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, discord.js

I would like to know how to retrieve all the information in a document and use it in a discord.js embed.

My current document:

[image: Current document]

My current code:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤/practice', function(err, db) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  db.collection("profiles").find({
    uuid: `${uuid}`
  }, {
    kitStatistics: 1
  }).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log(result);
  });
});

message.delete();
let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setAuthor(`Elorion.net`, `https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/06/7/1549795460-logo-elorionnetwork.png`)
  .setColor(color.elorion)
  .addField("Username", username)
  .addField("UUID", uuid)
  .addField("BuildUHC Elo", result)
  .addField("NoDebuff Elo", result)
  .addField("Debuff Elo", result)
  .addField("AxePvP Elo", result)
  .addField("Combo Elo", result)
  .addField("Archer Elo", result)
  .addField("Skin", `[Download](https://crafatar.com/skins/${uuid}.png)`)
  .setThumbnail(`https://crafatar.com/avatars/${uuid}.png?size=400&overlay=true`)
  .setFooter(`Ⓒ Elorion.net 2019. All rights reserved`);
message.channel.send(embed)
```

Comment: I edited the code a little bit after result: result[0].BuildUHC,..... But it still doesn't work, it puts undefined. I would like to do exactly the same my previous code which was in mysql, but now I want it in Mongo: http://pastebin.com/MKKJBx84
 Be careful, it's not the same data. As builduhcelo (in mysql) and BuildUHC then elo (in Mongo)
 I can also provide you with this if you want
 http://prntscr.com/mncppn
 http://prntscr.com/mncpyx
 http://prntscr.com/mncq5w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I look at your data structure, you really need to keep in mind what's an object and what's an array.

In your example `BuildUHC`, to get the elo property you would need `result[0].kitStatistics.BuildUHC.elo`.

I will leave the MDN artice of [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and [Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) here.

Comment: Thank you very much I hadn't thought about it but I was almost there during my tests before this post. I had put ```result[0].BuildUHC.elo```.